# Java doesn't work

Tags: java

I was writing a program on my laptop to run on my server in Java. However, my laptop has Java 7 running, my server Java 6. This messed up. I tried to upgrade my server by installing `openjdk-7-jre` and `openjdk-7-jdk` packages. This didn't work.

So I followed a guide helping me removing all `java` associated files and then re-install the needed packages. Something went wrong here. I installed all the available java 7 packages and now I cannot use the `java` command anymore. I probably screwed up, does anyone knows how to fix it? I tested it with both the 7 and 6 install, nothing works anymore.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: I think you should check if this packages are broken.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu server 11.10, how to fix broken packages?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using ubuntu server 11.10, how to fix broken packages? (from the comments)

On the command line type:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And you can also use this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And as written [here](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution):

> If the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.
>
> `$ sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status` (you can also use vi instead of nano)
>
> Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

It will fix the problem of broken packages.

Comment: Ok, but I'm on ubuntu server, no GUI?

Comment: @BrentRoose I broke a package on my Ubuntu here voluntarily to discover how to repair.

Comment: And the solution is on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After trying:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist.

The solution is to *edit* the `dpkg` status file manually:

```
$ sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Locate the corrupt package, and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.